# Where do npm background scripts go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a program which relies on another program being run so I added this `build` command to my `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "brunch watch --server",
    "build": "coffee server/modules/events/book_server.coffee &"
  }
```

so before I run my main script with `npm start` I run `npm run-script build` which makes my main script work, however when I quit my main script and then look for background processes with `bg` I get the message

```
> -bash: bg: current: no such job
```

so I decided to run `npm run-script build` again however the previous process must still have been running because I got the error message

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at errnoException (net.js:776:11)
  at Server._listen2._connectionKey (net.js:917:26)
  at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

and when I tried to run my main program again I got the error

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of null
```

My question is, where are these background scripts?

So far I have looked in all the obvious places including `package.json`'s directory the directory for `book_server.coffee` and in `node_modules` but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the background processes go into the background just running inside the OS but not attached to your shell's tty. To find them, use `jobs -l` or the `ps` command with something like `ps -ef`. You can use `grep` to filter the output, but what you need to find is the process ID (PID) of your build process so you can stop it with `kill <pid>`. You may also want to read up on `pgrep` and `pkill` which are handy for this process.

Note that in your example you use `bg` when it's not appropriate. `bg` is for this sequence: 1. start a job in your shell's foreground, 2. suspend that job with CTRL-Z, 3. use `bg` to tell the shell "allow this job to continue executing, but detached from my tty in the background". (again, `jobs` is what you are looking for here).

For the bigger picture, there's no need or benefit of running that `coffee` command in the background as it is just a simple compliation step that should take on the order of a few milliseconds.

For an amazingly-detailed "reread every year" level of depth, check out [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php).