# npm install not working: EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, tcp

I am unable to use `npm install` no way how much i tried.

npm: 2.14.12

node: v4.2.4

This is the error i get:

```
$ npm install --no-bin-links
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp/-/gulp-3.9.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EADDRINUSE 23.235.43.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp/-/gulp-3.9.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EADDRINUSE 23.235.43.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! errno EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect EADDRINUSE 23.235.43.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\??????\intern\npm-debug.log
```

I have tried `npm install`, `npm install --production`, and `npm install --no-bin-links` also i tried to remove node_modules folder and `npm cache clear` before i tried any of those commands.

I tried to lookup the IP and this was the result.

```
$ nslookup 23.235.43.162
*** 23.235.43.162 wurde von google-public-dns-a.google.com nicht gefunden: Non-existent domain.
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir-sass-compass": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is part of the `--verbose` output

```
...
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 15:19:47
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 15:19:47
npm http fetch GET https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir/-/laravel-elixir-4.2.0.tgz
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EADDRINUSE 23.235.43.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
...
```

I have this problem for a month now but at that time i was running on Windows 7 i recently upgraded to Windows 10.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11448).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do npm background scripts go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690551/where-do-npm-background-scripts-go)